# Disabling nginx cache for individual pages give 404

Tags: php, nginx, caching, fastcgi

I have a few pages I don't want cached:

1. example.com/login
2. example.com/register
3. example.com/password-reset

I have this rule in my nginx config but instead of disabling cache, it throws an NGINX 404 error for the specified url paths.

```
location ~ ^/(password-reset|register|login)/ {
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    if_modified_since off;
    expires off;
    etag off;
    proxy_no_cache 1;
    proxy_cache_bypass 1; 
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue and I cannot find any help about how to properly disable the cache for one page/endpoint without this 404 error.